# TensorFlow Image Classifier Returns the Same Label for each Image

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

I have made an image classifier to classify images of airplanes and rockets based on the tutorial at https://blog.francium.tech/build-your-own-image-classifier-with-tensorflow-and-keras-dc147a15e38e. I've written all of the code and it appears to function normally, except, when used to label testing images, it labels them all with the same class.

I've looked over the code on the webpage above, and it appears to match mine.

Here is my code. I've included all of it because I don't know where the issue is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from random import shuffle
from tqdm import tqdm
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *
from keras.optimizers import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline
import cv2

train_data = "C:/Users/Will Downs/image_training/training_data/"
test_data = "C:/Users/Will Downs/image_training/test_data/"

def one_hot_label(img):
  ohl = np.array([0, 0])
  label = img.split('.')[0]
  if label == 'Airplane':
     ohl = np.array([1,0])
  elif label == 'Rocket':
     ohl = np.array([0,1])
  return ohl

#This section loads and prepares the training and testing images:
def train_data_with_label():
  train_images = []
  for i in tqdm(os.listdir(train_data)):
    path = os.path.join(train_data, i)
    img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (64,64))
    train_images.append([np.array(img), one_hot_label(i)])
  shuffle(train_images)
  return train_images

def test_data_with_label():
  test_images = []
  for i in tqdm(os.listdir(test_data)):
    path = os.path.join(test_data, i)
    img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (64,64))
    test_images.append([np.array(img), one_hot_label(i)])
  shuffle(test_images)
  return test_images

#This section trains the model
training_images = train_data_with_label()
testing_images = test_data_with_label()
tr_img_data = np.array([i[0] for i in training_images]).reshape(-1,64,64,1)
tr_lbl_data = np.array([i[1] for i in training_images])

tst_img_data = np.array([i[0] for i in testing_images]).reshape(-1,64,64,1)
tst_lbl_data = np.array([i[1] for i in testing_images])

model = Sequential()

model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=[64,64,1]))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=5,strides=1,padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=5,padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=50,kernel_size=5,strides=1,padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=5,padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=80,kernel_size=5,strides=1,padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=5,padding='same'))

model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-3)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=tr_img_data, y=tr_lbl_data, epochs=50,batch_size=100)
model.summary()

#This section plots and labels the images
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,14))

for cnt, data in enumerate(testing_images[2:4]):

    y = fig.add_subplot(6,5, cnt+1)
    img = data[0]
    data = img.reshape(1,64,64,1)
    model_out = model.predict([data])

    if np.argmax(model_out == 1):
        str_label = "Airplane"
    else:
        str_label = "Rocket"

    y.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
    plt.title(str_label)
    y.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    y.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

I expected the program to plot each image in the testing folder along with a predicted label, but instead, it plotted each image with the same label for all of them, either "Airplane" or "Rocket."

Answer (score 0):

The bug is caused by this line, `if np.argmax(model_out == 1):`. Please change it to `if np.argmax(model_out) == 1:`. In the blog you post, they are the second one.